# Why this DOMXpath query merges sibling nodes values?

Tags: php, dom, xpath

Given the following code:

```
$html = "<h1>foo</h1><h2>bar</h2>";
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($document);
$h1Nodes = $xpath->query('//h1');
foreach ($h1Nodes as $h1Node) {
    var_dump($h1Node->nodeValue);
}
```

H1 tag contains only text node with the text 'foo'. Text 'bar' is in a sibling heading node (h2). I would expect the output to be 'foo'.

However, the output is 'foobar'.

Why?

Comment: `LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED` is used for turns off the automatic adding of implied html/body... elements. So If you are adding `LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED` then you must have to add `<html>` tag in your html. If you are removed `LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD` then your output is as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, for your comment, [hardik solanki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1355344/hardik-solanki).

It lead me to the answer: valid markup must have a root element.

Markup, which I've provided doesn't have one, and flags I've used prevent the library from adding one implicitly. So the first tag is treated as a root element and the result is a bit confusing.

Dropping those flags helps for this issue, but I am using them for a purpose. I just want to manipulate a snippet of HTML, and not a whole document. I want to get this snippet back (after transformations), by calling `DOMDocument::saveHTML()`. Without doctype/`<html>`/`<body>` tags.

I've ended up doing this:

- I add doctype/`<html>`/`<body>` tags to the HTML snippet I want to manipluate to have temporary a valid document
- load it with DOMDocument
- transform it the way I need
- save it with `DOMDocument::saveHTML()`
- get rid of excess doctype/`<html>`/`<body>` tags markup

It works.

Comment: You're doing stuff that DOM does itself. If you use `loadHTML()` without the options it will add html/body tags (like @hardik solanki said). And you can provide nodes to saveHTML() to save only the children of the body element. `foreach($xpath->evaluate('//body/*') as $node) $result .= $document->saveHtml($node);`